# Opensource messenger with API

Tags: open-source, messenger

Is there any opensource messenger with full API to use with AngularJS? I mean client side will be on AngularJS so I can call REST API to get all current messages, create group chat, get delivery status and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple that spring to mind:

https://tox.im/

> Originated on 4chan, focuses on privacy and security. Requires
>   knowledge of crypto to implement a client properly.

https://telegram.org/

> Not really open source. Has a protocol you can implement to provide
>   messaging functionality. Has caused a lot of drama in the past.

Comment: Is there something "easy" ready to use?

Comment: If you want them to be exclusively open source, then I can't think of anything.

http://www.slack.com has a nice API that is quite easy to use, though.